# Xorg/xcalib: change colors for only part of the screen?

Tags: x11, xorg, xrandr

Basically I want to be able to invert colors for the screen without upper and lower bands (main part w/out panels). I've recently leaned about `xcalib -invert -alter` and now wonder how difficult it can be to change colors for part of the screen only. TIA for any tips.

I've tried to find more about `XVidMode Extension` mentioned on `man xcalib` but could not find anything of use for this.